# Typescript - how to correctly use jsPDF in Angular2?

Tags: json, pdf, typescript, angular, jspdf

I have created an Angular2 application that generates JSON data. I want to save this JSON output into a file, preferably a PDF file. This application is written using Typescript.

I have used jsPDF for writing the JSON data into a PDF file. I have installed jsPDF package via npm using `npm install jspdf --save`. I have also added necessary links in index.html page. I made these changes to my application when it was running. I was able to save the JSON data to the file.

When I stopped and restarted the application, it did not start as expected. I got the following error:

> json-excel@1.0.0 start C:\Users*****\Documents\Projects\Angular\json-to-pdf
>
> tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite"
>
> app/components/app.component.ts(35,19): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'jsPDF'.

I'm  adding the code that I have used.

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
     "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.1",
     "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.1",
     "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1",
     "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.1",
     "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.1",
     "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.1",
     "@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.1",
     "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.1",
     "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.1",
     "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.7",
     "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
     "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
     "jquery": "^2.2.4",
     "jspdf": "^1.2.61",
     "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
     "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
     "systemjs": "0.19.27",
     "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
}
```

index.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JSON to PDF</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    ....

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.0.272/jspdf.debug.js"></script>

    ....

  </head>

  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body class="bg">
    <div>
      <app>Loading...</app>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.component.ts:

```
 import {Component} from '@angular/core';
 @Component({
   selector: 'app',
   template: `<button (click)="createFile()">Export JSON to PDF</button>`
 })
 export class AppComponent {
     public item = {
        "Name" : "XYZ",
         "Age" : "22",
         "Gender" : "Male"
     }
     constructor() {}
     createFile(){
        var doc = new jsPDF();
        var i=0;
        for(var key in this.item){
           doc.text(20, 10 + i, key + ": " + this.item[key]);
           i+=10;
        }
        doc.save('Test.pdf');
    }
 }
```

I think some import statement is missing in the app.component.ts file. Can someone point to the correct import statement if that is what is missing? If that is the error that I have made, can I know how to correctly us jsPDF in Angular2?

Thank you.

Comment: Facing same problem..Looking for someone to answer !!!!

Comment: Did you found out the answer for that ?? i got stucked in this error for a long time :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using jspdf with the latest angular cli version is really easy. Simply install jspdf from npm and use it something like this:

**app.component.ts**

```
// Note that you cannot use import jsPDF from 'jspdf' if you 
// don't install jspdf types from DefinitelyTyped
let jsPDF = require('jspdf');
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';

  constructor() {
    let doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.text("Hello", 20, 20);
    doc.save('table.pdf');
  }
}
```

***For old versions of angular cli based on systemjs instead of webpack***

[Here is a link](https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-2-cli-adding-third-party-libraries) to a description of one way to work with the `angular-cli` and libraries in `umd` or plain javascript. It basically involves using `declare jsPDF: any` together with importing the library in systemjs vendor files.

Comment: Still facing that same Error !!!! How to use that jspdf in Typescript ?

Comment: Oops, included the wrong vendor file in `angular-cli-build.js`. Try the updated config above.

Comment: @ Simon Bengtsson , See here my question is different :( I didn't find any files like app.component.ts,src/system-config.ts,angular-cli-build.js in my application . I have to find out first so that i can implement the steps as you mentioned in your answer .

Comment: This answer is mainly for people who use the [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli), but could be taken as inspiration for other systemjs projects. If you have another setup it would probably be easier if you created a new question where you can describe more in detail your code and build config. Feel free to ping me after that and I'll take a look.

Comment: @ Simon Bengtsson, Help me out from this if it's possible  ----->     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38661808/cant-find-name-jspdf-in-typescript

Comment: I have added the above changes but I'm getting a new error. `zone.js:461 Unhandled Promise rejection: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:4200/vendor/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js`

Comment: I was able to solve the error. I had do `typings install dt~jspdf --global --save` and restart the application. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The way you would do using Angular-cli and Angular 4 is 
first add jspdf to Scripts array in .angular-cli.json

```
"scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js"
      ]
```

then in the component add the following

```
import * as JSPdf from 'jspdf';
```

then in your class

```
  generatePdf() {
    let doc = new JSPdf();
    doc.text("Hello", 20, 20);
    doc.save('table.pdf');
}
```

Comment: How can i add scripts in  my ionic project ? i have installed jspdf using npm , stuck what to do next

Comment: even if you have installed jspdf using npm, there will be files like below directory structure node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js, you should add given lines as it is under list of scripts in specified file .angular-cli.json

Comment: In my case the relative path to node_modules starts from the same directory so I used "./node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js". Anyway this is the only answer that did the trick for me.